# PHP Database search- possibly with logging in, but I am not sure

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I have created a Database called ATHSEXAM.db using Python, it has 3 fields,

```
EMId, NAME, Surname.
```

I have created a class in PHP to connect to the DB, and a form in HTML to search the DB. However, it always returns null.

The program works, and I have tested the form. Variables always return a value, however, my search method is incorrect. I am using MAMP, and the DB is local to the webpage which I have created, so I have no idea why the it cannot find the results. If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

```
class details_db extends SQLite3 {  
    function __construct() {        //this function builds the database
            $this->open( 'ATHSEXAM.db' );       //opens the database created above to put in details_db
    }
}

if(isset( $_POST['SignIn'])){       
$EmiratesID = $_POST[ 'ID' ];       //creates a variable containing the company name entered
    $StudentName = $_POST[ 'ComName' ];     //creates a variable containing the address entered
    $StudentSurname = $_POST[ 'Surname' ];      //creates a variable containing the phone number entered

    echo($StudentName); 
    $EmiratesID = (int)$EmiratesID;
    echo($EmiratesID);
    echo($StudentSurname);

    $db = new details_db();     //opens details_db in the variable db

    $query = sprintf(
        "SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE EMId = '%s' AND Name = '%s' AND SURNANAME = '%s'",
        $EmiratesID, $StudentName, $StudentSurname
    );


    $results = $db->query( $query );        //puts the resultsof the query into a variable called results
    var_dump($results); 

    while($row = $results->fetchArray()){       //searches through results using the fetchArray function
        if($row){
            echo "student found";       //returns the boolean true
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i fail to follow right in the first sentence. you have a database with 3 fields?

Answer (score 1):

i guess its a typo in the query, i am not sure since i have no eye on the db

```
$query = sprintf( "SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE EMId = '%s' AND Name = '%s' AND  SURNANAME = '%s'", $EmiratesID, $StudentName, $StudentSurname );
```

SURNAME must be Surname, and Name must be NAME, because mysql is strict with names

```
$query = sprintf( "SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE EMId = '%s' AND NAME = '%s' AND  Surname = '%s'", $EmiratesID, $StudentName, $StudentSurname );
```